# Subtracting months/years from boost::posix_time::ptime

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I have a `boost::posix_time::ptime` that points to `March 31st 2010` like this:

```
ptime p(date(2010, Mar, 31));
```

I would like to subtract a month (and possibly years) from this date. From the docs I see these two operators: `ptime operator-(time_duration)` and `ptime operator-(days)` but none of them can work with months/years. If I try and do:

```
time_duration duration = hours(24 * 30);
ptime pp = p - duration;
```

I'm getting March 1st and if I'm trying:

```
ptime pp = p - days(30);
```

I'm still getting March 1st, while I'd like to get February 28th.
How can I achieve my desired result? (I would like to get the desired result also when subtracting a month from March 28, 29, 30)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

boost::posix_time::ptime::date() operator returns date object. You can call greg_year, greg_month etc. for this object.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion led me to the solution. Using the `boost::gregorian::date` class I was able to find "date durations", that have weeks/months/years.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you already know that not all months have 30 days so you can't subtract with 30 days in general.

You should ask yourself what you mean by "subtract a month".

Comment: I already said in my question my interpretation of "subtract a month", which to my knowledge is the standard one.

Comment: So by subtracting one month from February 5, you mean January 5?
And by subtracting one month from March 30, you mean February 30, or...? I am sorry, I was not aware there was a standard interpretation of subtracting a month. What is that standard interpretation anyway?

Comment: Subtracting one month from March 30 would give you February 28 or February 29, depending on the year.
I can refer you to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#snap_to_details where they explain this behavior, which may seem somewhat "awkward" at first, but is what you would expect